# jQuery abnormal behavior of input file not always updating image

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I am trying to have an image upload input which submits automatically on change. This works perfectly... Most of the time, how ever sometimes it doesn't update the image being displayed. I have a colleague who believes this may be a race condition problem.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="@imageString" />

    using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateLogo", "Blah", FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="logo-button-group">
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    Change Image<input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
                </span>

                <br/>

                <input type="submit" id="image-change-btn" value="Upload Image" style="visibility:hidden" />
            </div>
        }
```

Supported by the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#page-content-wrapper #image").change(function () {
        $("#logo-change-btn").click();
    });
});
```

The idea is that when the input file changes, that it'll automatically submit the hidden submit button.

This works fine, problem is, sometimes the `image` isn't uploaded. Most of the time it is, how ever, sometimes it takes two attempts (by selecting the image using the `file input` twice).

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Did you verify that is not cached?

Comment: Good question, I'll have to look into that.